# Expected function be called not being called

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

I'm sure what I'm doing is quite an easy fix but I can't seem to spot it. The function under test is this:

```
function signIn(credentials) {
  return $http({
    url: 'auth/authenticate',
    skipAuthorization: true,
    method: 'POST',
    data: credentials
  }).then(function (result) {
    saveCredentials(result.data);
  });
};
```

Which calls the **saveCredentials** function after the promise from the $http returns. I'm testing it like so:

```
(function() {
describe('Unit Testing: Auth-service Factory',function() {

    var AuthService, httpBackend, deferred;
    beforeEach(module('flowlens'));

    // Mock values for jwt and store
    beforeEach(function() {
        module(function($provide) {
            $provide.value('jwtHelper',{
                decodeToken: function() {
                    return {
                        contact: 'Joe Bloggs'
                    }
                }
            });
            $provide.value('store',{
                set: function() {}
            });
        });
    });

    // Get the service
    beforeEach(function() {
        inject(function(_AuthService_, _$httpBackend_) {
            AuthService = _AuthService_;
            httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        });
    });

    describe('should load the service',function() {
        it('service should be loaded',function() {
            expect(AuthService).not.toBeUndefined();
        });
    });

    describe('signIn',function() {
        it('should return data when calling signIn', function() {
            spyOn(AuthService,'saveCredentials');

            httpBackend.expectPOST('auth/authenticate').respond({msg: 'Success'});
            AuthService.signIn();
            httpBackend.flush();

            expect(AuthService.saveCredentials).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
    });
});
}());
```

It's the expect just above this line that is failing with :

```
Expected spy saveCredentials to have been called
```

Why is this not being called? I added a log message into the function and I can see that it is being called in the code - is this a $scope.digest issue? Note that if I add the following:

```
it('should return data when calling signIn', function() {
            spyOn(AuthService,'saveCredentials');

            httpBackend.expectPOST('auth/authenticate').respond({msg: 'Success'});
            AuthService.signIn().then(function(result) {
                AuthService.saveCredentials(result);
                // Assuming that I have mocked it before the call
            });
            httpBackend.flush();

            expect(AuthService.saveCredentials).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
```

It will pass. But this is a fake test as I could go ahead and change the actual call to an entirely different method and it will still pass.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think you need `then` in your unit-test. You just call `signIn` and spyOn `saveCredentials` then (after `flush`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try your expectation in your `then(...)` function:

```
it('should return data when calling signIn', function() {
    spyOn(AuthService,'saveCredentials');

    httpBackend.expectPOST('auth/authenticate').respond({msg: 'Success'});

    AuthService.signIn().then(function(result) {
        expect(AuthService.saveCredentials).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    httpBackend.flush();        
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - unfortunately that didn't work either.

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle or plunker I can look at?

Comment: I don't sorry - but I believe I have chased down the problem. It appears that the test fails because the AuthService object is actually empty. So it's essentially checking for a function that can't be called